# Tallest vs Loftiest

Tags: differences, comparatives

How is the usage of the two words different? I think they mean one and the same. Are they?

Comment: "Lofty" is probably more often used figuratively than literally: eg, "He has lofty ideas."  When used literally it's still used to emphasize the height vs simply state it in a forthright fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something is "lofty" it is literally "sky-high".  Lofty mountain peaks.  The word can be used figuratively: "lofty sentiments, lofty goals".

If *lofty* is used literally of things that are high but not truly up among the clouds, it is exaggeration or hyperbole.   *We sat in the lofty seats at the stadium.*

*Tall* describes someone or something (like a building) of considerable height, without any hyperbole.  It, too, can be used figuratively:  "a tall order", that is, something difficult to accomplish, or "a tall tale", a tale that is hard to believe.

Comment: +1 I failed to do justice to the hyperbolic and figurative element, though I was groping for it. I'd forgotten the usage of lofty peaks, probably because I myself never use the word, though I'm a big fan of the Alps.

Answer (score 0):

I think buildings are getting on for the only referents here, as mountains are high not tall. People can be tall but lofty only in extreme cases.

So if you talked about the Burj Khalifa being "lofty", how would this be different from calling it tall? I'd think you were a journalist, is what; and that is not a compliment.

On the other hand, there is at least one real difference: if you took a seat on top of the Burj, on the outside, I would call it a **"lofty perch"** and never "a tall perch" or a "high perch". Perhaps because the emphasis is on your vulnerability not the building; also, a *literal* perch, as in what parrots sit on, does not go down to the ground, so it cannot really be tall. Just the instinct of a native speaker.